# Ensure text field begins with specific value: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a text field that needs to start with a two letter word as a prompt. This two word is mandatory and users should not be able to remove it or add text before it.

I've tried using `substr()` to check the first two characters but this seems clunky

```
if ($("#myinput").val().substr(0,2) != "ab") {
// alter value
}
```

The problem I'm having is that people could remove the first character first, second character first, or highlight the text and remove them simultaneously. I've thought to just check for any possible ways someone might alter this text but it seems lengthy and like there has to be a better way.

Is there a good way to make this text "undeletable" or do I just need to check for all possible ways someone might alter the initial text?

Thanks

Comment: Do these two letters need to be inside the textfield?

Comment: If the two letters must be there, and are not to be removed, changed or edited then they should not be in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example that doesn't require jQuery.

It basically adds an event listener for the `input` event and sets the first character(s) initially. In addition, it prevents the characters from being removed, making them "undeletable", and enforces that they remain the same.

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('enfore-rules');
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    var element = e.target,
        firstCharacters = 'ab';
    
    if (element.value.length < firstCharacters.length) {
        element.value = firstCharacters;
    } else {
        element.value = element.value.replace(/^.{2}/, firstCharacters);
    }
});
```

```html
<input text="text" id="enfore-rules" value="ab"/>
```

Alternatively, you could also insert two characters outside of the `input` element like this:

```css
.input-masked {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.input-masked:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'ab';
  left: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}
.input-masked input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.4em;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-masked">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of validating that the input box starts with 'ab'. I would suggest you split the ab out into a span right before the textbox and concat 'ab' to whatever the user enters into the text box instead of validating.

https://jsfiddle.net/tegk10ex/

```
var validateinput = function($input) {
     if($input.val().match(/^ab/gmi) == null)
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
};
$('#input').on('input', function(event) {
   validateinput($(this));

});
validateinput($("#input"));
```